# Smooth Scrolling, Cross-Browser, Without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below you will find a script I created for **smooth scrolling** when clicking local links. It is done via `transform` (no *jQuery*). As seen, I have implemented it using both *inline CSS* as well as *external style sheets*. I recommend the inline version, as it might be difficult to guess the index of the relevant style sheet.

The problem however, is that the actual movement of the scrollbar, happens after the transform is applied. Thus, if you click a link before scrolling transition is done, the code misbehaves.

Any thoughts on a solution to this?

---

**EDIT:**

I know there are [jQuery solutions](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) and [third party polyfill libraries](http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/) out there. My goal, however, was to recreate the *jQuery* functionality in plain vanilla JavaScript.

---

**My Script:**

```js
// Get style rule's declaration block
function getStyleDeclaration(styleSheet, selectorText) {
  const rules = styleSheet.cssRules;
  return Array.from(rules).find(r => r.selectorText === selectorText).style;
  // for (let i = 0; i < rules.length; i += 1) {
  //   if (rules[i].selectorText === selectorText) return rules[i].style;
  // }
}

// Get specific style sheet, based on its title
// Many style sheets do not have a title however
// Which is main reason it is preferred to work with
// inline styles instead
function getStyleSheet(title) {
  const styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
  return Array.from(styleSheets).find(s => s.title === title);
  // for (let i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i += 1) {
  //   if (styleSheets[i].title === title) return styleSheets[i];
  // }
}

function scrollToElement_ExternalStyleSheet(anchor, target) {
  anchor.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const time = 1000;
    // Distance from viewport to topof target
    const distance = -target.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    // Modify external style sheet
    const transStyle = getStyleDeclaration(document.styleSheets[1], ".trans");
    transStyle.transform = "translate(0, " + distance + "px)";
    transStyle.transition = "transform " + time + "ms ease";

    const root = document.documentElement; // <html> element
    root.classList.add("trans");

    window.setTimeout(() => {
      root.classList.remove("trans");
      root.scrollTo(0, -distance + window.pageYOffset);
    }, time);
  });
}

function scrollToElement_InlineStyle(anchor, target) {
  const root = document.documentElement;
  anchor.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const time = 900;
    const distance = -target.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    root.style.transform = 'translate(0, ' + distance + 'px)';
    root.style.transition = 'transform ' + time + 'ms ease';

    window.setTimeout(() => {
      root.scrollTo(0, -distance + window.pageYOffset);
      root.style.transform = null; // Revert to default
      root.style.transition = null;
    }, time);
  });
}

function applySmoothScroll() {
  const anchors = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  const localAnchors = Array.from(anchors).filter(
    a => a.getAttribute("href").indexOf("#") != -1
  );
  localAnchors.forEach(a => {
    const targetString = a.getAttribute("href");
    const target = document.querySelector(targetString);
    // scrollToElement_ExternalStyleSheet(a, target);
    scrollToElement_InlineStyle(a, target);
  });
}

applySmoothScroll();
```

```css
.box {
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 200%;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
}

a {
  color: black;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.trans {
  transform: translate(0, -100px);
  transition: transform 900ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="s0" class="box"><a href="#s1">Click Me!</a></div>
<div id="s1" class="box"><a href="#s2">Click Me!</a></div>
<div id="s2" class="box"><a href="#s0">Click Me!</a></div>
```

Comment: Your technique is not scrolling. You're moving the contents without changing the scroll position and the native scrollbar is not controllable. It always updates according to current content length vs container length. To put it bluntly, what you want is not possible without scrolling, so your method is fundamentally flawed if you want the scrollbar (the real browser scrollbar) to update according to your scroll-mock. Of course, you could disable the scrollbar altogether, build your own, out of HTML elements and update it as you see fit.

Comment: What's wrong with [smoothscroll](http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/)? It's a polyfill for the [W3C draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-window-interface)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thanks for looking through. Response to your two comments: 1) I know that there are jQuery solutions that work, so I wanted to recreate it with vanilla JS. Example: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/ . Any idea how the underlying JS works there? 2) I know there are several solutions and libraries out there, but wanted to create my own to improve as a developer and be less reliant on third party bloat.

Comment: `window.scroll()`, `window.scrollTo()` and `scrollBy()` are **native** methods. How they work is beyond what a web developer has to know. That part falls to browser developers. The polyfill simply covers browsers which haven't implemented the proposed native methods yet. Don't mistake a polyfill for a library. If this is a subject that really interests you, you might want to reverse engineer velocity.js's code, as it tends to have remarkable results in terms of performance and behavior on most, if not all devices.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiGheorghiu , I'll have a look at `velocity.js` as soon as I can find some time. I don't consider myself just a web developer :) I wanted to figure out how the polyfill works, and how jQuery accomplishes what I linked to above via plain vanilla JS. Certainly, if jQuery can do it, it must be possible with vanilla JS?